# Avoiding duplicate Null Checks (Pass a User Control as a Parameter)

Tags: c#, user-controls, null, datareader

I am working with an application that reads multiple dates from an Oracle database and assigns it to `DateTimePickers`.

```
dtpAdjSerDt.Value = dr.GetDateTime(iadj_service_date);
```

However, this assignment requires a null check as the values in the db could be `null`.

I would like to be able to create an extension method that returns a default value if the value is null.

```
public static DateTime fSafeGetDateTime(OracleDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
        return reader.GetDateTime(colIndex);
    else
        return DateTime.Now;
}
```

There is one problem with this approach:  If the db value is null then the DateTimePicker.Checked should be false. But using the strategy I suggested above it would be set to true.

Is there a way for me to do something like this:

```
public static DateTime fSafeGetDateTime(OracleDataReader reader, int colIndex, DateTimePicker control)
{
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(colIndex))
        return reader.GetDateTime(colIndex);
    else
    {
        control.Checked = false;
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

If this is not possible what would be the cleanest way (avoiding duplicate code) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you just return a `DateTime?` and let the caller do the defaulting:

```
public static DateTime? SafeGetDateTime(this OracleDataReader reader, int colIndex)
{
    return reader.IsDBNull(colIndex) ? null 
                                     : (DateTime?) reader.GetDateTime(colIndex);
}
```

Now you can use:

```
DateTime fromReaderOrNow = reader.SafeGetDateTime(1) ?? DateTime.Now;
```

And if you need the control part:

```
DateTime? fromReader = reader.SafeGetDateTime(1);
if (fromReader == null)
{
    control.Checked = false;
}
DateTime fromReaderOrNow = fromReader ?? DateTime.Now;
```

If you *really* need to do that in multiple places, you can wrap up a method to do - and you won't be repeating the `SafeGetDateTime` code.

(I would encourage you to separate our your database code further from your UI code to start with, to be honest.)

Comment: -I am not very familiar with Nullable Types.  Does using nullable types here prevent a run time error when initializing fromReader?
-Is DateTime fromReaderOrNow = fromReader ?? DateTime.Now; the same as DateTime fromReaderOrNow = (formReader != null ? formReader : DateTime.Now)
- Although your last suggestion (in the parenthesis) is not possible (since I am working for someone else who is directing the architecture) could you please explain what that would look like in this example.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Azzi: I can't really go into the details of how you'd separate it with no other context - and it wouldn't be suitable for an SO comment thread anyway. I'm not sure what you mean about a run time error when initializing `fromReader` - it's still using the `SafeGetDateTime` method... that's what's preventing the error. You're right about the meaning of the null coalescing operator (`??`) though.